# How to recover the path from a pair of (parent, child) in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, breadth-first-search

I have a dictionary  `key:set`

the `key` is a child node with string, and its `value` is a `set` contain its parent node's string.

For example

```
startnode = "hit"
endnode = "cog"
mydict =  {'hot': {'hit'}, 'dot': {'hot'}, 'lot': {'hot'}, 
       'dog': {'dot'}, 'log': {'lot'}, 'cog': {'dog', 'log'}}
```

`'cog': {'dog', 'log'}`: means `dog` and `log` both point to child node `cog`

How to recover all possible paths from any two nodes?

In this example, the results will be

```
res = [["hit","hot","dot","dog","cog"],
       ["hit","hot","lot","log","cog"]]
```

I tried to use `loop`, but I fail since each child can have `arbitrary` parent. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a dictionary such that the keys are parents and the values are children of the keys. Then run any path finding algorithm (`bfs` or `dfs`) to find all the possible paths.

To create the dictionary from what you have:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
adjacency = defaultdict(set)
for key in mydict:
   for node in mydict[key]:
     adjacency[node].add(key)
```

Result is:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'dog': {'cog'},
             'dot': {'dog'},
             'hit': {'hot'},
             'hot': {'dot', 'lot'},
             'log': {'cog'},
             'lot': {'log'}})
```

You can read [this](https://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) article for explanation and implementation of bfs and dfs in python.

Comment: is it possible to return two paths as in my `res`?